# dojo ignores element when parent div syle display none

Tags: dojo

My select is in a div element that has the style attribute `display:none` because it's only shown in a popup dojo ignores these and I see a normal html select but the same 3 lines outside the popup shows a perfect dijit select form

I tried visiblility hidden but then the bpupop plugin from jquery fails to show the div

```
<select name="ToServer" id="ToServer" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
    <option value="1" label="breitseite">breitseite</option>
    <option value="2" label="pepe">pepe</option>
    <option value="3" label="grow">grow</option>
    <option value="4" label="hurricane">hurricane</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong or how I can force dojo to restyle the div when the popup gets opened

**update:**
i had the parser the problem was i was calling 1 object twice with the same id but i fixed it now it's in dojo style but it only shows me 1 option of the select (same html output)

after dojo "render" it looks like that:

```
<table class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitDownArrowButton dijitSelect dijitValidationTextBox" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode,tableNode,focusNode" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" id="ToServer" widgetid="ToServer" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false"><tbody role="presentation"><tr role="presentation"><td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,_popupStateNode" role="presentation" popupactive="true"><span role="option" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel ">breitseite</span></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="? " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><input type="hidden" name="ToServer" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" value="1" aria-hidden="true"></td><td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="? " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></td></tr></tbody></table></dd></div><div class="dijitPopup dijitMenuPopup" style="visibility: visible; top: 174px; z-index: 1000; right: auto; left: 619px; display: none; " role="presentation" id="ToServer_dropdown" dijitpopupparent="ToServer"><div style="overflow: visible; top: 0px; width: 67px; visibility: visible; " class="dijit dijitMenu dijitReset dijitSelectMenu dijitValidationTextBoxMenu dijitMenuPassive" role="presentation" id="ToServer_menu" widgetid="ToServer_menu" tabindex="0"><table class="dijitReset dijitMenuTable" role="listbox" tabindex="0" data-dojo-attach-event="onkeypress:_onKeyPress" cellspacing="0" style="">
<tbody class="dijitReset" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"><tr class="dijitReset dijitSelectSelectedOption dijitValidationTextBoxSelectedOption dijitMenuItemSelected dijitMenuItem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="dijit_MenuItem_0_text dijit_MenuItem_0_accel" id="dijit_MenuItem_0" aria-disabled="false" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_0" aria-selected="true">
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemIconCell" role="presentation">
    <img src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.0/dojo/resources/blank.gif" alt="" class="dijitIcon dijitMenuItemIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode">
</td>
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" colspan="2" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" id="dijit_MenuItem_0_text">breitseite</td>
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemAccelKey" style="display: none" data-dojo-attach-point="accelKeyNode" id="dijit_MenuItem_0_accel"></td>
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuArrowCell" role="presentation">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="arrowWrapper" style="visibility: hidden">
        <img src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.0/dojo/resources/blank.gif" alt="" class="dijitMenuExpand">
        <span class="dijitMenuExpandA11y">+</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

pepe
    
    
        
            
            +
        
    

    
        
    
    grow
    
    
        
            
            +
        
    

    
        
    
    hurricane
    
    
        
            
            +

Comment: Don't tag other subjects if they aren't relevant. Referring to jquery.

Comment: it acturaly was jquery the popup addon i used made a ifream out of it - very strange if u ask me

Comment: If you can provide an example page where it's hosted, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

All elements will get Dojo styling if they are within the `<body>`  tag that has a theme set.

Your problem isn't actually with styling, but it is most likely to do with parsing. I would advise that your `dijit/form/Select` isn't getting parsed.

You can confirm this by running from console:

```
require(["dojo/parser"], function(parser){
  parser.parse();
});
```

Comment: i had the parser the problem was i was calling 1 object twice with the same id but i fixed it now it's in dojo style but it only shows me 1 option

Comment: You can specify a node to parse as well. parser.parse("elementId")